# RMySQL via ssh tunnel

Tags: r, rmysql

I'm using RStudio on OSX and have a local vm running Ubuntu.  I'm having issues with RMySQL connecting to mysql running on the local vm via ssh. I've tried forwarding port 3307 via

```
ssh -L 3307:d.local.internal.com:3306 ubuntu@d.local.internal.com
```

followed by the following in r

```
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), host = "127.0.0.1", user = "root", password = "pass", port=3307)
```

I'm still getting

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (57)
```

Any ideas?  I am able to successfully connect via SequelPro with the same ssh and mysql credentials.

Comment: Try `telnet` to that port on that host and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 ubuntu@d.local.internal.com`

I bet d.local.internal.com can't resolve d.local.internal.com hostname, because you may not have DNS entry for d.local.internal.com in the DNS server used by d.local.internal.com or for that matter a /etc/hosts entry.

Also you don't need to setup your local port to 3307, you can use 3306, provided you don't have anything listening on 3306 on your host.